# Ionic 2 ion-Searchbar ionClear not firing on button click

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a searchbar in my toolbar as follows:

```
  <ion-toolbar color="clarity">
    <ion-searchbar
      [(ngModel)]="searchText"
      [showCancelButton]="false"
      (ionInput)="onInput($event)"
      (ionClear)="onClear($event)">
    </ion-searchbar>
  </ion-toolbar>
```

and a function in the corresponding TS file:

```
   onClear(event){
     this.searchText = "";
   }
```

But the 'onClear' event never gets hit when the searchbars little 'x' is clicked.. why is that?

Comment: In my case, the event started firing after I stopped automatic builds and re-ran ionic serve, seems like live-reload didn't get the change right when I added the statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After @Ivario18 suggested I change the clear to (ionCancel), I added the (ionCancel) **as well as** the (ionClear):

```
<ion-toolbar color="clarity">
  <ion-searchbar
    [(ngModel)]="searchText"
    [showCancelButton]="false"
    (ionInput)="onInput($event)"
    (ionClear)="onClear($event)"
    (ionCancel)="onCancel($event)">
  </ion-searchbar>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Now the clear is working...

Answer (score 2):

Change it to `(ionCancel)` You're probably using an outdated ionic guide

Answer (score 1):

I found that I was able to use just the (ionCancel) if I include the [showCancelButton]="true". Without it, the cancel didn't work at all, and the (ionClear) seemed to be breaking my infinite-scroll directive.

Comment: This answer is the only one that worked for me in Ionic 4.